# Outlook 2013 "Calendar permission" properties is disabled.

Tags: outlook, calendar

**Hi,**

We are using Outlook 2013 in our client systems. In one of the systems, we are facing outlook calendar permission issue. In this system, "Calendar permission" properties is not activated ( Not Highlighted )so we are not able to add the user ID into this calendar permission. We have logged with Domain user name. We want to enable the ADD option in Calendar permission TAB. So any suggestion on making it enable in Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

As a most basic troubleshooting step, we need to confirm if the problem is mailbox account related or client related. Ask another user setup a profile(not in the existing profile) with this client, see if the issue would occur. Meanwhile, ask the affected user setup a profile on a normal user's client.

Meanwhile, based on my experience, this issue would occur to the shared mailbox which is setup as the second mailbox in a profile. For example, User A has full access on User B's mailbox. When User A setup an Outlook profile and User B's mailbox is auto-mapped, the Calendar Permission will not gray out. If it's in this situation, setting up a separate profile would resolve this issue.